Are other interpretations of the "a" article possible?
There is a short dialogue:

Where is the soup? - The soup is in a big saucepan on the gas cooker.

I'm interested in the meaning that the indefinite article conveys. It seems like there are several big saucepans on the gas cooker and we tell another person that one of them contains the soup. I'm sure that this interpretation is a legit one. Are other interpretations of this particular sentence possible?

No, it doesn't necessarily imply that there are several saucepans, just that the questioner probably hasn't seen that particular one before. Speaking to someone in your own household who is familiar with the kitchen equipment, you might say "It's in the big saucepan".

What other interpretation do you think might be correct? Or why do you think yours is wrong?

I don't think that mine is wrong. I just want to know if there are other ways to interpret that dialogue. While doing exercises related to the articles I need to imagine the situation that takes place in order to insert the right article. My short dialogue represents one of the exercises correctly solved. I was able to solve it by using the thought process that I've described in my question. I just want to know if there are other ways to reason in order to improve and expand my understanding of the subject matter.

In this case, the use of "the" and the indefinite article "a" indicates that the listener knows the general location (the gas cooker) but not the specific container where the soup is.
The indefinite article "a" signals that the container (a big saucepan) is the one where the soup can be found.
This usage aligns with the idea that the exact container hasn't been specified but is described by its size and type. Importantly, it does not imply that there are multiple big containers.
It means that if the listener finds the big saucepan, they will find the soup.

James, can I still use the form with the indefinite article "a" if the listener knows that this container exists among other containers in the house?

@snailontheslope If there is more than one big saucepan and the listener cannot identify which one is being referred to, you can still use "a big saucepan." If there is only one big saucepan, use "the big saucepan." However, there are no strict rules.

Soup, like most liquids, is an uncountable noun. The indefinite article "a" essentially means "one" (ie "an apple" is one apple) and you can't use a number with uncountable nouns, because then you'd be counting it.
Things like pans and bowls are countable nouns. You can have one bowl, two bowls, etc. You can therefore use them as countable measures - a bowl of soup, or a pan of soup. The indefinite article in your example refers to the pan, not the soup in it.
Even if the soup was being cooked in multiple pans as you suggest, it is still collectively "the soup" (or even just "soup" - no article needed). You can make general statements about non-countable nouns such as "water is a compound of hydrogen and oxygen", and that is true of all water everywhere, whether it's in a glass, a lake, or one of the many oceans of the world. Of course, in your example, it isn't referring to all soup in general - the soup must be something tacitly understood or previously referred to. In this case, it's the soup that is being cooked in the kitchen. So, in the context of your example, it is correct to use the definite article - the soup.
There are other contexts where you could say "a soup" - if you were speaking about types of soup (eg gazpacho is a soup and minestrone is also a soup). You may also hear a serving of soup like "a bowl of soup" abbreviated to just "a soup". At a restaurant, you might order "two soups" for you and your dining partner which essentially means two bowls, or servings of soup.
